How do I rewrite all PHP scripts to get handled by index.php in .htaccess?
My software written in PHP recalls scripts only through index.php as follows: index.php?r=something.php.
How can I hide the GET parameter (including the script to be launched), putting the call to the r parameter in an .htaccess file?

So you are asking how you can get your site e.g. http://example.com/something.php to run index.php?r=something.php when accessed?

I guide most people to using FallbackResource. And just to be clear, it is not htaccess's responsibility to "hide" anything, it is your application's responsibility to create links in the format you want, and then it is also your application's responsibility to figure things out in your central router.

Do you mean this kind of directive? RewriteRule ^foo$ /index.php?r=something.php [L] This will set an invisible redirection from http://example.com/foo to http://example.com/index.php?r=something.php

Maybe you should also have a look at Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained

Sounds like you want something like this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?r=$1 [L]

Which means: "If the requested file does not exist as a file and the requested file does not exist as a directory, call index.php and add the original requested URI as GET parameter q".
So if you request https://example.com/doesnotexist.php (and doesnotexist.php does indeed not exist), index.php?r=doesnotexist.php will be called.
